# Как Сделать Кнопку "Вниз" Неотображаемой в Конце Страницы без Плагинов и jQuery?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Пожалуйста подскажите решение с простым javascript (без плагина или jQuery) для исчезновения кнопки "Вниз" в конце веб страницы! Я - чайник (полный) в javascript, и составил как мог (базируясь на том, что нашел в инете) вот такой код (внизу), но кнопка "Вниз" все равно отображается.

```
<button onclick="scrollWin()" id="bottom" title="Go to bottom">&#10148;</button>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="up" title="Go to top">&#10148;</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

 function scrollFunction() {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250) 
   {
    document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("up").style.display = "block";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("up").style.display = "none";
              } 

  if (document.body.scrollHeight < 250 || document.documentElement.scrollHeight < 250){
    document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "none";}}


  function scrollWin() {
   window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
   document.documentElement.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);}

  function topFunction() {
   document.body.scrollTop = 0;
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;}

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сложно определить по вопросу и коду что именно вам нужно, но насколько смог понять - настолько сделал. Вариант не кроссбраузерный, в ie8- вряд ли будет работать, но если нужно будет разберетесь.

---

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop < 250) {
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("up").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("up").style.display = "block";
        }
    if (document.body.scrollHeight - (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight) < 250) {
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("up").style.display = "block";
    }
}

scrollFunction();

function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
}
#up {
   left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#bottom {
  left: 40px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="up" title="Go to top">top</button>
    <button onclick="scrollWin()" id="bottom" title="Go to bottom">bottom</button>
```

Comment: вам огромнейшее спасибо за подсказку! Кнопка "Вниз" исчезает внизу страницы, но мне нужно было чтобы обе кнопки появлялись одновременно после продвижения по странице вниз на высоту экрана, поэтому я просто поменял 'block' на 'none' в первоий строке в первой if:

Comment: function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop < 250) {
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("up").style.display = "none";
    }
    Надеюсь, что я сделал правильно. У меня еще несколько вопросов: 1) какой также простой код можно добавить для плавного появления и исчезновения кнопок "вверх" и "вниз"? 2) Важно как размещать кнопки на странице, вместе вверху слева (как написали вы в CSS) или одна вверху, а другая внизу справа? 3) Будет этот скрипт работать на всех браузерах (кроме IE8) и моб. устройствах?

Comment: Prevolley, я прогнал тест-страницу через Chrome, Mozilla, IE, и Opera, код работает только в Chrome и Opera. Я попробовал продублировать document.body... добавив 

        document.documentElement.scrollTop
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight

но ничего не вышло и, более того, кнопка "Вниз" вообще исчезла. Не знаю, что сделать дальше, т.к. не знаю javascript. Вы могли бы написать crossbrowser код?

Comment: Так неужели больше никто не откликнется с простым решением - кроссбраузерный код для отображения/неотображения кнопки "Вниз"?